# Is it possible to set parameter positions for default commandlets?

Tags: powershell

For example I would like the `Select-Object` commandlet to interpret `Get-ChildItem|Select-Object 1` as `Get-ChildItem|Select-Object -First 1`

I have been getting by with "Wrappers" like this for my most common commandlets:

```
function Select-Object{
    [CMDletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObect, 
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [int]$First,
        [Parameter(Position = 2)]
        [int]$Last
    )
    $input | Select-Object -First $First -Last $Last
}
```

But there are sometimes buggy and I always rewrite it to add more parameters.

I have been reading the docs and have not found anything other than parametersplicing.

It does not have to be an official solution. So if anyone has come up with a solution to this I would like to know.

PS: I know this is can lead to confusing code, but I am intending to only use it for an interactive\terminal sessions. Doing `gci | sel 1` is infinitely more preferable to  `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -First 1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wrappers like this you should use a [`ProxyCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0). Most of the code below can be auto-generated for you via its [`.Create(..)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand.create?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-proxycommand-create(system-management-automation-commandmetadata)):

```bash
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Select-Object))
```

Using only the 2 parameters you're interested in `-First` and `-Last` in addition to the pipeline parameter, the function would look like this:

```
function sel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [int] $First,

        [Parameter(Position = 2)]
        [int] $Last
    )

    begin {
        $wrapper  = { Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object @PSBoundParameters }
        $pipeline = $wrapper.GetSteppablePipeline($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $pipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }
    process {
        $pipeline.Process($InputObject)
    }
    end {
        $pipeline.End()
    }
}
```

Now you can use positional binding without problems:

```bash
0..10 | sel 1   # for `-First 1`
0..10 | sel 1 1 # for `-First 1` `-Last 1`
```

As for *parameter splicing* you might referring to what's known as *Splatting* in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell). For that you can look into [**about Splatting**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3). As an example the code above is using splatting with the [automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psboundparameters).

Comment: Amazing, I will use this to learn more about this area. Thanks so much!